# Increment the value of the column of which the Serial no is greatest

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table(table_name), the columns of which are Sno,count. The default value of count being 1.
If wanna increment the value of the count column where Sno is, say 1..

```
UPDATE table_name SET count=count+1 where Sno=1;
```

it works!!!

But what if I wanna increment the value of count where Sno is Max?

```
Sno  count
 1    2
 2    1
```

Basically I need help creating hybrid of :

```
UPDATE table_name SET count=count+1 where Sno=1;
```

&

```
select MAX(Sno) from table_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
UPDATE table_name t1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(t2.Sno) AS max_Sno 
            FROM table_name t2) AS t3 ON t3.max_Sno = t1.Sno 
SET t1.count = t1.count + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
update table_name
  set count = count+1
where sno = (select max(sno) from table_name)
```

is the obvious approach (and works in most RDBMS), ***but not in MySQL***:

> You can't specify target table 'table_name' for update in FROM clause

See answers based on a join or further indirection for approaches that work.

Comment: MySQL doesn't allow you to do that.  You're reading from the table you're writing to and get the error `You can't specify target table 'table_name' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: @MatBailie Another reason to continue to try and avoid MySQL! (One day I might succeed!)

Comment: MySQL 8 looks promising.

Comment: **MySQL said:** #1093 - Table 'table_name' is specified twice both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, I'm on my phone, but I think you need to jump through an irritating hoop for this.

Use a sub-query on the table you're updating, but "hide" that fact from MySQL by nesting the sub-query in another sub-query.

```
UPDATE
  table_name
SET
  count = count + 1
WHERE
  Sno = (SELECT Sno FROM (SELECT MAX(Sno) AS Sno FROM table_name) deref)
```

The `JOIN` approach also works *(from @MadhurBhaiya)* as shown here...

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f7a1f6/1